# Excel worksheets not seeing their VB code

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

The form buttons and controls on all my worksheets suddenly stopped working. The behavior is like what you see before you respond to the security prompt-- "enable macros?", that is, when you mouse-over a control button the mouse icon doesn't morph into an arrow. Even when I manually check the "Enable macros" box on the options page the problem persists. When I run the same .xlsm file on my laptop it works fine so it doesn't seem to be the fault of the my project software. The Microsoft Help Center says that under my license the two computers running Excel simultaneously should have full VB development capabilities. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the Developer tab is enabled?. If not, enable the developer tab. Also, enable necessary Trust options in the "Trust Center" and check your results.

Comment: Check to see if there was a recent Office update. Many times I have had security reset after an update. Also ensure the file is not being opened in compatibility mode for some reason. I have had that issue in the past too.

Comment: Thanks. The Trust Center settings are all set to trust and allow all macros and controls. The developer tab is not required for control buttons on a worksheet to call the VB code when they are clicked only for when adding a control to the sheet. But I tried it anyway to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

One of the automatically installed patches for Office may have created this issue for you

Check to see if the following may apply
Three symptoms are described but  the third may be what you are seeing

> a Microsoft Excel workbook that includes ActiveX control (forms3) on
>   a computer that has MS14-082  installed, the Excel macro may not work
>   on computers that do not have MS14-082 installed.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036